# unable to build gazebo package in ROS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while running rosmake gazebo. i get the following error:

/home/pragyan/tredext/biome_simulator/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/audio_video/AudioDecoder.cc:105:49: error: ‘avcodec_decode_audio2’ was not declared in this scope

I tried to uncomment the use of this function and tried to make it the next error was related OREG. Can anyone just tell me the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11917/unable-to-build-gazebo-package-in-ros./) by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-11**:
Could you give more details like OS, ROS version and details of error in preformatted text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i just downloaded the latest version of gazebo and it worked fine.. thanks for ur reply :)

---

Originally posted by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) with karma: 66 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1